# React Native - Length of placeholder takes precedence in multiline-input's height

Tags: javascript, android, typescript, react-native, textinput

## Problem:

My text input placeholder could take a max of 2000 characters. As long as my user starts typing in the text input, the placeholder goes away but the text input **height does not automatically shrink back down**.

AFAIK, the height of my multiline text input is being set based on the original length of my placeholder text. Is there anyway to get around this?

## My Code:

```
import { Input } from 'react-native-elements';

interface Props {
    placeHolder: string;
    onChangeText: (text: string) => void;
}

const MyTextInput = (inputs: Props) => (
    <View>
        <Input
            inputStyle={{ textAlignVertical: 'top' }}
            placeholder={inputs.placeHolder}
            onChangeText={(text) => inputs.onChangeText(text)}
            multiline={true}
            maxLength={2000}
        />
    </View>
);

export default MyTextInput;
```

## Screenshots:

Long placeholder:
[image]

User inputs text:
[image]

Text Input height doesn't shrink:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, I added an additional `value` prop such that whenever user starts typing, `inputs.onChangeText(text)` will update the `value`, and the height of the input will scale automatically to fit the content. When `value` is empty or cleared, simply show `placeHolder`.

```
interface Props {
    placeHolder: string;
    onChangeText: (text: string) => void;
    value: string;
}

const MyTextInput = (inputs: Props) => (
    <View>
        <Input
            inputStyle={{ textAlignVertical: 'top' }}
            value={inputs.value}
            placeholder={inputs.placeHolder}
            onChangeText={(text) => inputs.onChangeText(text)}
            multiline={true}
            maxLength={2000}
        />
    </View>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

adding minHeight and maxHeight on inputStyle should fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

set clearTextOnFocus props will work

```
<Input
        clearTextOnFocus={true}
        inputStyle={{ textAlignVertical: 'top' }}
        placeholder={inputs.placeHolder}
        onChangeText={(text) => inputs.onChangeText(text)}
        multiline={true}
        maxLength={2000}
    />
```